# Can't set acl recursively in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, acl

I'm trying to use acl to be able to modify files without changing ownership of the files, but acl is throwing an error (I'm guessing it's my syntax).

This is on a new server running Ubuntu 18.04. I've done this in the past on CentOs.

My syntax is:

```
setfacl -Rdm u:username:rwx /var/www/example.com/public_html
```

I expect this to recursively add permissions for "username" recursively for all files in the path specified, but instead I'm getting the error:

```
setfacl: Option -m: Invalid argument near character 3
```

Comment: The most straightforward reason would be that there is no such user as `username` on your system: what does `getent passwd username` say?